# how to create a setup file with launch condition

Tags: c#

i don't have basic knowledge of .net

but i have assigned a work to create a setup file for a project which must satisfy the condition such the setup file must check the present of the .net and sql while installing if not it should automatically install it

so guide by step by step 
for
1.registry key 
2.prerequisites
3.launch condition

.net3.5 and sql server2005
using vs 2008

pls help me friends

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using the Setup Project in VS.NET, [here it is an example of how to add prerequisites](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Prerequisites_in_Setup.aspx)